# Associate App with .gpx extension - Intent filter Not working?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want my application to be on the list to open .gpx from anywhere in the android environment. the none of the intent filters I tried didn't work, what do I need to add to make it work?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gpx" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Android does not do much with file extensions. Find the corresponding MIME type and create an `<intent-filter>` for `file` and `content` schemes for that MIME type, rather than work with file extensions.

Comment: apparently, it is not working on the emulator but it is working on a real phone

Comment: It will not work well on Android 7.0+ devices, as the `file` scheme is mostly banned.